# Cannot setup MPI wrappers - fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpi.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, msys2, boost-mpi

I am having issues setting up MPI with the Boost C++ Library. I suspect I'm not setting up my MPI wrappers correctly. However, I'm likely wrong! I cannot run: `mpicc -show` or `mpicc -showme`.

Thus, I cannot find my correct library path for my MPI implementation. I am running terminal through Visual Studio Code 1.76.0, but also have also tried MSYS2 terminal to run these commands without success.

After cloning boost and running bootstrap.bat I modified project-config.jam with the wrapper settings from the boost library MPI [guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html). However, I don't think these wrappers are suitable for my computer, I am assuming my processor has intel impi enabled (which I'm not sure about). My Processor: Intel(R) Core (TM) i5-1235U 1.30 GHz.

Not sure if this is applicable but just in case my g++ --version is: (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0.

Thankyou for taking your time to view this and help me out! :)

Project-config.jam below:

```
project-config.jam
# Boost. Build Configuration 
# Automatically generated by bootstrap.bat 

using mpi : mpiicc :
      <library-path>/softs/intel/impi/5.0.1.035/intel64/lib
      <library-path>/softs/intel/impi/5.0.1.035/intel64/lib/release_mt
      <include>/softs/intel/impi/5.0.1.035/intel64/include
      <find-shared-library>mpifort
      <find-shared-library>mpi_mt
      <find-shared-library>mpigi
      <find-shared-library>dl
      <find-shared-library>rt ;
 
import option ; 
 
using msvc ; 
 
option.set keep-going : false ;
```

once running ./b2 outputs the following mess in terminal:

```
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit (cached) [1]
    - default architecture     : x86 (cached) [1]

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.
    - symlinks supported       : no  (cached)
    - junctions supported      : yes (cached)
    - hardlinks supported      : yes (cached)
    - compiler supports SSE2   : yes (cached) [2]
    - compiler supports SSE4.1 : yes (cached) [2]
    - has synchronization.lib  : yes (cached) [2]
    - has std::atomic_ref      : no  (cached) [2]
    - has statx                : no  (cached) [2]
    - has statx syscall        : no  (cached) [2]
    - has BCrypt API           : yes (cached) [2]   
    - has init_priority attribute : no  (cached) [2]
    - has stat::st_blksize     : no  (cached) [2]   
    - has stat::st_mtim        : no  (cached) [2]   
    - has stat::st_mtimensec   : no  (cached) [2]  
    - has stat::st_mtimespec   : no  (cached) [2]  
    - has stat::st_birthtim    : no  (cached) [2]  
    - has stat::st_birthtimensec : no  (cached) [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtimespec : no  (cached) [2]
    - has fdopendir(O_NOFOLLOW) : no  (cached) [2]
    - has POSIX *at APIs       : no  (cached) [2] 
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_constexpr          : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_final              : yes (cached) [2] 
    - cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_lambdas            : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_template_aliases   : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_thread_local       : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_constexpr          : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_final              : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_lambdas            : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_template_aliases   : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_thread_local       : yes (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached) [3]
    - has_icu builds           : no  (cached) [2]
    - zlib                     : no  (cached) [4]
    - bzip2                    : no  (cached) [4]
    - lzma                     : no  (cached) [4]
    - zstd                     : no  (cached) [4]
    - has_lzma_cputhreads builds : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_decltype           : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_basic_alignas      : yes (cached) [2]
    - iconv (libc)             : no  (cached) [2]
    - iconv (separate)         : no  (cached) [2]
    - icu                      : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_defaulted_moves    : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_functional     : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_override           : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_range_based_for    : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_scoped_enums       : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_smart_ptr          : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_static_assert      : yes (cached) [2]
    - native atomic int32 supported : yes (cached) [2]
    - has message compiler     : yes (cached) [2]
    - native syslog supported  : no  (cached) [2]
    - pthread supports robust mutexes : no  (cached) [2]
    - compiler supports SSSE3  : yes (cached) [2]
    - compiler supports AVX2   : yes (cached) [2]
    - gcc visibility           : no  (cached) [2]
    - sfinae_expr              : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_unified_initialization_syntax : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_initializer_list : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_chrono         : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_numeric_limits     : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_array          : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_atomic         : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_allocator          : yes (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_explicit_conversion_operators : yes (cached) [2]
    - long double support      : yes (cached) [2]
    - std::fstream is moveable and swappable : yes (cached) [2]
    - Has Large File Support   : yes (cached) [2]
    - Has attribute init_priority : no  (cached) [2]

warning: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration
note: failed.  See http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html
note: for configuration instructions or pass --without-python to
note: suppress this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets
\- libbacktrace builds      : no  (cached) \[2\]
\- libbacktrace builds      : no  (cached) \[3\]
\- addr2line builds         : no  (cached) \[2\]
\- addr2line builds         : no  (cached) \[3\]
\- WinDbg builds            : yes (cached) \[2\]
\- WinDbg builds            : yes (cached) \[3\]
\- WinDbgCached builds      : yes (cached) \[2\]
\- BOOST_COMP_GNUC \>= 4.3.0 : no  (cached) \[2\]
\- cxx11_hdr_thread         : yes (cached) \[2\]
\- cxx11_hdr_regex          : yes (cached) \[2\]
\- compiler supports SSE2   : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- compiler supports SSE4.1 : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- has synchronization.lib  : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- has std::atomic_ref      : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has statx                : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has statx syscall        : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has BCrypt API           : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- has init_priority attribute : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has stat::st_blksize     : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has stat::st_mtim        : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has stat::st_mtimensec   : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has stat::st_mtimespec   : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has stat::st_birthtim    : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has stat::st_birthtimensec : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has stat::st_birthtimespec : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has fdopendir(O_NOFOLLOW) : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- has POSIX \*at APIs       : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_constexpr          : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_final              : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_lambdas            : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_noexcept           : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_nullptr            : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_template_aliases   : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_thread_local       : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_constexpr          : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_final              : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_lambdas            : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_noexcept           : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_nullptr            : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_template_aliases   : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_thread_local       : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- has_icu builds           : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- zlib                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- bzip2                    : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- lzma                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- zstd                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- has_lzma_cputhreads builds : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_decltype           : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_basic_alignas      : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- iconv (libc)             : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- iconv (separate)         : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- icu                      : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_moves    : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_functional     : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_override           : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_range_based_for    : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_scoped_enums       : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_smart_ptr          : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_static_assert      : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- native atomic int32 supported : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- has message compiler     : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- native syslog supported  : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- pthread supports robust mutexes : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- compiler supports SSSE3  : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- compiler supports AVX2   : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- gcc visibility           : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- sfinae_expr              : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_unified_initialization_syntax : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_initializer_list : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_chrono         : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_numeric_limits     : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_array          : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_atomic         : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_allocator          : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_explicit_conversion_operators : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- long double support      : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- std::fstream is moveable and swappable : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- Has Large File Support   : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- Has attribute init_priority : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- libbacktrace builds      : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- libbacktrace builds      : no  (cached) \[6\]
\- addr2line builds         : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- addr2line builds         : no  (cached) \[6\]
\- WinDbg builds            : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- WinDbg builds            : yes (cached) \[6\]
\- WinDbgCached builds      : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- BOOST_COMP_GNUC \>= 4.3.0 : no  (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_thread         : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- cxx11_hdr_regex          : yes (cached) \[5\]
\- compiler supports SSE2   : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- compiler supports SSE4.1 : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- has synchronization.lib  : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- has std::atomic_ref      : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has statx                : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has statx syscall        : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has BCrypt API           : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- has init_priority attribute : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has stat::st_blksize     : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has stat::st_mtim        : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has stat::st_mtimensec   : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has stat::st_mtimespec   : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has stat::st_birthtim    : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has stat::st_birthtimensec : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has stat::st_birthtimespec : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has fdopendir(O_NOFOLLOW) : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- has POSIX \*at APIs       : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_constexpr          : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_final              : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_lambdas            : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_noexcept           : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_nullptr            : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_template_aliases   : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_thread_local       : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_constexpr          : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_final              : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_lambdas            : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_noexcept           : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_nullptr            : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_template_aliases   : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_thread_local       : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- has_icu builds           : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- zlib                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- bzip2                    : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- lzma                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- zstd                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- has_lzma_cputhreads builds : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_decltype           : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_basic_alignas      : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- iconv (libc)             : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- iconv (separate)         : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- icu                      : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_moves    : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_functional     : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_override           : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_range_based_for    : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_scoped_enums       : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_smart_ptr          : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_static_assert      : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- native atomic int32 supported : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- has message compiler     : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- native syslog supported  : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- pthread supports robust mutexes : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- compiler supports SSSE3  : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- compiler supports AVX2   : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- gcc visibility           : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- sfinae_expr              : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_unified_initialization_syntax : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_initializer_list : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_chrono         : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_numeric_limits     : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_array          : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_atomic         : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_allocator          : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_explicit_conversion_operators : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- long double support      : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- std::fstream is moveable and swappable : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- Has Large File Support   : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- Has attribute init_priority : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- libbacktrace builds      : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- libbacktrace builds      : no  (cached) \[8\]
\- addr2line builds         : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- addr2line builds         : no  (cached) \[8\]
\- WinDbg builds            : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- WinDbg builds            : yes (cached) \[8\]
\- WinDbgCached builds      : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- BOOST_COMP_GNUC \>= 4.3.0 : no  (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_thread         : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- cxx11_hdr_regex          : yes (cached) \[7\]
\- compiler supports SSE2   : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- compiler supports SSE4.1 : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- has synchronization.lib  : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- has std::atomic_ref      : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has statx                : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has statx syscall        : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has BCrypt API           : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- has init_priority attribute : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has stat::st_blksize     : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has stat::st_mtim        : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has stat::st_mtimensec   : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has stat::st_mtimespec   : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has stat::st_birthtim    : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has stat::st_birthtimensec : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has stat::st_birthtimespec : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has fdopendir(O_NOFOLLOW) : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- has POSIX \*at APIs       : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_constexpr          : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_final              : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_lambdas            : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_noexcept           : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_nullptr            : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_template_aliases   : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_thread_local       : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_auto_declarations  : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_constexpr          : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_final              : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_hdr_mutex          : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_hdr_tuple          : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_lambdas            : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_noexcept           : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_nullptr            : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_rvalue_references  : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_template_aliases   : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_thread_local       : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- cxx11_variadic_templates : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- has_icu builds           : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- zlib                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- bzip2                    : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- lzma                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- zstd                     : no  (cached) \[4\]
\- has_lzma_cputhreads builds : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_decltype           : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_basic_alignas      : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- iconv (libc)             : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- iconv (separate)         : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- icu                      : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_defaulted_moves    : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_functional     : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_override           : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_range_based_for    : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_scoped_enums       : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_smart_ptr          : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_static_assert      : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- native atomic int32 supported : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- has message compiler     : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- native syslog supported  : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- pthread supports robust mutexes : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- compiler supports SSSE3  : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- compiler supports AVX2   : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- gcc visibility           : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- sfinae_expr              : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_unified_initialization_syntax : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_initializer_list : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_chrono         : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_numeric_limits     : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_array          : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_atomic         : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_allocator          : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_explicit_conversion_operators : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- long double support      : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- std::fstream is moveable and swappable : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- Has Large File Support   : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- Has attribute init_priority : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- libbacktrace builds      : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- libbacktrace builds      : no  (cached) \[10\]
\- addr2line builds         : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- addr2line builds         : no  (cached) \[10\]
\- WinDbg builds            : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- WinDbg builds            : yes (cached) \[10\]
\- WinDbgCached builds      : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- BOOST_COMP_GNUC \>= 4.3.0 : no  (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_thread         : yes (cached) \[9\]
\- cxx11_hdr_regex          : yes (cached) \[9\]

\[1\] msvc-14.3
\[2\] msvc-14.3/debug/address-model-32/link-static/threadapi-win32/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
\[3\] msvc-14.3/debug/address-model-32/build-no/link-static/threadapi-win32/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
\[4\] link-static
\[5\] msvc-14.3/release/address-model-32/link-static/threadapi-win32/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
\[6\] msvc-14.3/release/address-model-32/build-no/link-static/threadapi-win32/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
\[7\] msvc-14.3/debug/link-static/threadapi-win32/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
\[8\] msvc-14.3/debug/build-no/link-static/threadapi-win32/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
\[9\] msvc-14.3/release/link-static/threadapi-win32/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
\[10\] msvc-14.3/release/build-no/link-static/threadapi-win32/threading-multi/visibility-hidden

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : building
    - chrono                   : building
    - container                : building
    - context                  : building
    - contract                 : building
    - coroutine                : building
    - date_time                : building
    - exception                : building
    - fiber                    : building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : building
    - graph_parallel           : building
    - headers                  : building
    - iostreams                : building
    - json                     : building
    - locale                   : building
    - log                      : building
    - math                     : building
    - mpi                      : building
    - nowide                   : building
    - program_options          : building
    - python                   : building
    - random                   : building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : building
    - stacktrace               : building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : building
    - thread                   : building
    - timer                    : building
    - type_erasure             : building
    - url                      : building
    - wave                     : building

...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 39526 targets...
...updating 124 targets...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\debug\\address-model-32\\link-static\\threading-multi\\cartesian_communicator.obj
cartesian_communicator.cpp
C:\\boost\\boost/mpi/config.hpp(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpi.h': No such file or directory

    call "bin.v2\standalone\msvc\msvc-14.3\address-model-32\architecture-x86\msvc-setup.bat"  >nul

cl /Zm800 -nologo "libs\\mpi\\src\\cartesian_communicator.cpp" -c -Fo"bin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\debug\\address-model-32\\link-static\\threading-multi\\cartesian_communicator.obj"     -TP /wd4675 /EHs /GR /Zc:throwingNew /Z7 /Od /Ob0 /W3 /MDd /Zc:forScope /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:inline
\-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_MPI_SOURCE=1 "-I." "-I\\softs\\intel\\impi\\5.0.1.035\\intel64\\include"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\debug\\address-model-32\\link-static\\threading-multi\\cartesian_communicator.obj...  
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\debug\\address-model-32\\link-static\\threading-multi\\broadcast.obj
broadcast.cpp
C:\\boost\\boost/mpi/config.hpp(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpi.h': No such file or directory

    call "bin.v2\standalone\msvc\msvc-14.3\msvc-setup.bat"  >nul

cl /Zm800 -nologo "libs\\mpi\\src\\text_skeleton_oarchive.cpp" -c -Fo"bin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\release\\link-static\\threading-multi\\text_skeleton_oarchive.obj"     -TP /wd4675 /EHs /GR /Zc:throwingNew /O2 /Ob2 /W3 /MD /Zc:forScope /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:inline /Gw /favor:blend -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_MPI_SOURCE=1 -DNDEBUG "-I." "-I\\softs\\intel\\impi\\5.0.1.035\\intel64\\include"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\release\\link-static\\threading-multi\\text_skeleton_oarchive.obj...
...skipped \<pbin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\release\\link-static\\threading-multi\>libboost_mpi-vc143-mt-x64-1_82.lib for lack of \<pbin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\release\\link-static\\threading-multi\>broadcast.obj...
...skipped \<pC:\\boost\\stage\\lib\>libboost_mpi-vc143-mt-x64-1_82.lib for lack of \<pbin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\release\\link-static\\threading-multi\>libboost_mpi-vc143-mt-x64-1_82.lib...
...skipped \<pbin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\release\\link-static\\threading-multi\>libboost_mpi-variant-vc143-mt-x64-1_82-static.cmake for lack of \<pbin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\release\\link-static\\threading-multi\>libboost_mpi-vc143-mt-x64-1_82.lib...
...skipped \<pC:\\boost\\stage\\lib\\cmake\\boost_mpi-1.82.0\>libboost_mpi-variant-vc143-mt-x64-1_82-static.cmake for lack of \<pbin.v2\\libs\\mpi\\build\\msvc-14.3\\release\\link-static\\threading-multi\>libboost_mpi-variant-vc143-mt-x64-1_82-static.cmake...
...failed updating 92 targets...
...skipped 32 targets...
```

Comment: Did you install this package in msys2: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-msmpi](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-msmpi)

Comment: @drescherjm Thankyou so much! This has allowed me to use this command. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The system mpi.h header is in this msys2 package: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-msmpi

You can install it with the following command:
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-msmpi`